# Merging 2 Conference Bridges On asterisk

Tags: asterisk, pbx

Hi I have confbridge X  with participants ABC  and another Confbridge Y with participants DEF . Some times i want to merge both conferences without interrupting ongoing conversation so that everyone will be one conference room either X or Y .

How can we achieve this via dial-plan or AMI .

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic conference(without room exist) feature and create calls using Originate command to application Confbridge.

Then I want redirect exist call(xxx) to this conference room via AMI:

("Action: Redirect"  "ActionID: TransferCall"   "Exten: NNNN"  "Context: default"  "Priority: 1" "Channel: SIP/NNN-00000071" ).

For a full list of AMI actions for ConfBridge, please see: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge+AMI+Actions

Answer (score 0):

You can use ChannelRedirect action.

It do almost imidiate transfer. If you want go without userenter message, you should create enother bridge without messages and transfer to it.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ChannelRedirect